# Setting image sizes with array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

The array `$file_ary` contains images from a file input. It looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Screenshot from 2015-03-06 15:41:58.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2b8cbW
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 87810
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Screenshot from 2015-03-06 15:45:00.png
            [type] => image/png
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpcpmK2A
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 93532
        )

)
```

What I would like to do is crop each of those file. And I thought of setting new widths and heights in another array.

```
  $imgSizes = array(
    '100' => '100',
    '150' => '150',
    '130' => '400'
  );


 if(!empty($file_ary)) {

        foreach($file_ary as $file) {

            foreach($imgSizes as $key => $val) {

                echo $file['name'];
                echo '<br>';
                //$resizeObj -> resizeImage(100, 100, 'crop');
                //$resizeObj -> saveImage('images/100/'.$this->id.'.gif', 100);

            }

        }

      }
```

Right now `foreach($imgSizes as $key => $val) {` is returning 6 images ... one for each key and one for each val. I would like to use the key and val from the `$imgSizes` array to set the new size `$resizeObj -> resizeImage($key, $val, 'crop');`, rename and save it `//$resizeObj -> saveImage('images/'.$key.'/'.$this->id.'.gif', $key);`

I m not sure how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand good your question you would have to rewrite a bit the structure of the array, e.g.:

```
$imgSizes = array(
    0 => array(
        'width'  => '100',
        'height' => '100'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'width'  => '150',
        'height' => '150'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'width'  => '130',
        'height' => '400'
    )
  );

if(!empty($file_ary)) {
    foreach($file_ary as $file) {
        foreach($imgSizes as $key => $val) {
            echo $file['name'];
            echo '<br>';
            $resizeObj -> resizeImage($val['width'], $val['height'], 'crop');
            $resizeObj -> saveImage('images/'.$val['width'].'/'.$this->id.'.gif', $val['width']);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you .. .but it's still echoing 6 items.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to show 6 items? You are cropping 2 images, 3 sizes each, could you specify how many you would like to see?